# How to get the required values from a class using JAVA8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have **List`<RecipeDto>` recipes**. I want to get only the **keywords** and **ingredeients** from **RecipeDto** class using stream. This code is not working fine.

```
List<String> keywordsAndIngredientsStream = 
recipes.stream().forEach(recipeDto -> {
            recipeDto.getIngredients().forEach(ingredient -> ingredient.toLowerCase());
            recipeDto.getKeywords().forEach(keywords -> keywords.toLowerCase());})
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Cannot resolve method **collect**

Comment: please copy the error from logcat and add it in the question

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram since `forEach` is a `void` terminal operation, you wouldn't have any output to collect from it. Question is, what `List<String>` are you even trying to collect?

Comment: Please add an input and an output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a list of the *ingredients* and *keywords*, just do:

```
ArrayList<RecipeDTO> recipes = new ArrayList<RecipeDTO>() {{

    add(new RecipeDTO(Arrays.asList("onion", "rice"), Arrays.asList("yummy", "spicy")));
    add(new RecipeDTO(Arrays.asList("garlic", "tomato"), Arrays.asList("juicy", "salty")));

}};

List<String> ingredientsAndKeywords = recipes.stream()
        .flatMap(recipe -> Stream.concat(recipe.getIngredients().stream(), recipe.getKeywords().stream()))
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .collect(toList());

for (String ingredientsAndKeyword : ingredientsAndKeywords) {
    System.out.println(ingredientsAndKeyword);
}
```

**Output**

```
onion
rice
yummy
spicy
garlic
tomato
juicy
salty
```

**Update**

Given the new requirements, just do:

```
List<String> ingredientsAndKeywords = recipes.stream()
                .map(recipe -> Stream.concat(recipe.getIngredients().stream(), recipe.getKeywords().stream())
                        .map(String::toLowerCase).collect(joining(" ")))
                .collect(toList());

        for (String ingredientsAndKeyword : ingredientsAndKeywords) {
            System.out.println(ingredientsAndKeyword);
        }
```

**Output**

```
onion rice yummy spicy
garlic tomato juicy salty
```

Comment: Sir i want to get the "keywords" and "ingredients" of "index 0" of "RecipeDto" in the 0th index of "List <String> ingredientsAndKeywords" .But i am unable to get the desired results.You are requested to please update your Answer as per desired results.It is only giving me the "ingredients" at 0th index yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to really collect the *ingredients* and *keywords* stream (as the variable name suggests) into one with the mapping to lowercase, you could `concat` them as:

```
Stream<String> keywordsAndIngredientsStream = recipes.stream()
        .flatMap(rec -> Stream.concat(rec.getIngredients().stream(), rec.getKeywords().stream())
                .map(String::toLowerCase));
```

and further, if you wanted to collect it to a `List<String>` as:

```
List<String> keywordsAndIngredientsList = keywordsAndIngredientsStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```